# Visualizing a file based on byte ranges in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have data that describes the makeup of a binary file. Each point of data specifies a start and end range in bytes as well as a type:

```
[0x046270, 0x057574, "type1"]
[0x057574, 0x05BF20, "type2"]
[0x05BF20, 0x05EF80, "type1"]
[0x05EF80, 0x05F050, "type2"]
```

I would like to be able to visualize the file by coloring sections and getting something similar to what can be seen in the old Windows disk defragmentation utility.

[image: Windows Disk Defragmenter]

I have tried using matplotlib's stacked bar chart for this, but I am seeing some issues and think I may be misusing it for this purpose. Is there a name for the type of graph below or any clean way of going about rendering this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic stacked graph with 256 sector images. To make it two tiers like the presented image, you need to add in `ax2` or change the structure of the data There is a The process is very heavy, so it takes some time to output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
FAT_No = np.arange(0, pow(2,8))
sector_st = random.choices(['type1','type2','type3','type4'], k=256)
value = [1]*256
before = ['before']*256
df = pd.DataFrame({'before':before,'fat_no':FAT_No, 'sector':sector_st, 'value':value})

df
    before  fat_no  sector  value
0   before  0   type1   1
1   before  1   type1   1
2   before  2   type4   1
3   before  3   type2   1
4   before  4   type2   1
... ... ... ... ...
251 before  251 type2   1
252 before  252 type2   1
253 before  253 type3   1
254 before  254 type2   1
255 before  255 type4   1

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,3),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

color = {'type1':'b','type2':'g','type3':'r','type4':'w'}

for i in range(len(df)):
    ax.barh(df['before'], df['value'].iloc[i], color=color[df['sector'].iloc[i]], left=df['value'].iloc[:i].sum())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the helpful reply! Thank you.